# Installing codonW

Tags: windows-10, command-line, windows-installation

I want to install codonW application (http://codonw.sourceforge.net/) in my Windows 10 system. The zip file for installation has 2 files with no extension and 7 C files. I tried compiling the C files from cmd, but I don't know what has to be done with those files without an extension. How do I install this software?

Comment: Sounds like you downloaded the source code for the application instead of the application itself. On that page you linked, under the "Downloading and Installation" section, take a look at number 4: "Win 32bit". Click that and it will take you to the download of the .exe - although that program hasn't been updated in nearly 15 years and you should expect it to have problems with Windows 10.

Comment: Yeah, what @Sam_Forbis said except I don't see any reason that you should have a problem with this command line app with Windows 10.  A non gui app written in ANSI C that doesn't call a single win32 API should work just fine "forever".. (addendum).. runs just fine..